# transfer to tz account, which is balance 0 but is a inactive delegate,need pay burn fee?

Tags: transfer

As [Stephen Andrews says](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/PROTO_003_FEES.md):

> An inactive implicity account is a tz account with nil (0) balance which isn't registered as a delegate/baker

Question: I transfer to a tz account, which has balance 0 but is an inactive delegate, do need I pay a burn fee?

The rpc now I haven't found way to set a delegate to inactive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my account reduced by 0.257 tz?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/why-is-my-account-reduced-by-0-257-tz)

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, it cost .257 to *create* a new implicit account (or re-create an old one that has become inactive with a 0 balance).

Delegate status will switch from active to inactive if no operations are made before the grace period. There is no way to force the delegate status to inactive. To become an active delegate, you need to send a delegation operation for the tz* address (which incurs a fee).

Comment: if a address is 0 balance but has set as delegate, so transfer xtz to this address not need pay burn fee?

Comment: Correct. It costs to set the delegate though so keep that in mind. The other way is to keep 0.000001 tez in the account.