# Why is my account reduced by 0.257 tz?

Tags: transactions

Sometimes while trading, the balance in my tz1 account will be reduce by 0.257 tz. After I successfully traded, my account balance would be out of the currency transferred with the transaction fees, but I would also lose an additional 0.257 tz.

account: `tz1Nm5kshYha1PaUqaDR4T9HnciyfiBM7rd6`

operation hashes:

- op7cmHet8aMYwK659bGhgmDMQVAWL5d8Q7i7wqVLuvpXQHyDiXd
- oozEMD8YVuNY7Q3PCSMBeP9YguyKAZsnrjwLw4DKcwdZWYzUhLw

Comment: Please provide more details. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: transaction success,but my account lost 0.257,operation hash : op7cmHet8aMYwK659bGhgmDMQVAWL5d8Q7i7wqVLuvpXQHyDiXd, oozEMD8YVuNY7Q3PCSMBeP9YguyKAZsnrjwLw4DKcwdZWYzUhLw

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 8):

Both the transactions that you are referencing are the fist transaction to a new address. As you can see on the [operations cost table for Protocol 004](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/protocols/004_Pt24m4xi.html#gas-and-fees), 0.257 tz is burned "if the recipient is a new address".

See the second part of [this answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/788) to get details on the reason of this cost and [this one](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/787/148) for the explanation of the 0.257 tz value.